# Evaluate variable in twig only once

Tags: twig, locale, evaluate

In twig layout I get current locale (symfony v>2.3) with

```
{{app.request.locale}}
```

Is any convenient way to tell twig to evaluate this variable only once and use it further in other places and not to evaluate every time?

Or I need to set twig variable and use it further?

Comment: assign the value in the main template and use the variable in the other place

Answer (score 0):

use the `set` directive e.g:

```
{% set locale = app.request.locale %}
{# when you want to print it everywhere else: #}
{{ locale }}
{# you can also use it in other directives #}
{% if locale == 'eng' %}
...dosomething
{% endif %}
```